# Create a local playlist based on array of IDs for YTPlayerView YTPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, ytplayerview, ytplayer

currently we're using on YTPlayerView:

```
open func load(withVideoId videoId: String) -> Bool
```

to load single videos. However in some cases we have a series of videos which need to play one after the other. Is it possible to create and load an array of video IDs locally, i.e. a playlist?